# Altium - design rule check does not match with signal integrity for impedance

Tags: altium, signal-integrity, drc, controlled-impedance

I have designed a 2-layer PCB with Altium Designer. I placed an impedance rule of 50 Ohm in trace width rule section. When I run the design rule check, there is no impedance error.

However, when I run signal integrity and calculate impedance, the values around 250 Ohm is displayed.

Does anybody know the problem and its solution?

Please consider the screen shots of the Altium Designer:

[image: layer stack]

[image: rules]

[image: rule check]

[image: signal integrity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having has two reasons

1. Altium requires a power/ground plane defined as a reference. Unfortunately Altium is not capable of calculating the impedance on a 2 layer board with a copper pour as a reference. See [this whitepaper](https://www.altium.com/documentation/19.0/display/ADES/((Controlled+Impedance+Routing))_AD)
2. The stackup and track width you have used will not give you 50 Ohms unless you use track widths of 1.5mm.

Solution: make it a 4 layer board, or use a thinner board thickness